# Is there a way to implement a grid layout with Ratchet?

Tags: javascript, css, ratchet, ratchet-2

I am looking for something like what bootstrap provides, columns and rows, in Ratchet.

Comment: Of course there is "a way" but it doesn't come built-in with the framework. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I am trying purecss.io seems to be working ok.

Comment: If you find a good solution, post it as the answer, I'd be interested to see what you came up with. Thanks.

Comment: I am still playing around with stuff I will post the results of my project in a few days.

Answer (score 1):

I used Ungrid https://github.com/chrisnager/ungrid. It is super simple and has some responsive support (1 break point).

Comment: its not good. because objects with not `same height` in `same row` are **not shown in same vertical align**

Answer (score 0):

I just adopted the ui-grid-x CSS from JQuery Mobile...worked like a charm.